# Why does jQuery .html() not get full html code?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button. When I click on it I want to take HTML from a div. This div contains some table rows.

### Tiny markup

```
<div class="new">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>New</strong></td>
        <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>
</div>​
```

When I want to take the HTML and put it in a table something go wrong.

What I get from `$('.new').html()`

```
<strong>New</strong>
hi
```

It looks like jQuery does not take the `<tr><td>` parts.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/PQXxV/

Comment: Why are you having a <tr> inside a <div> and not a <table>?

Comment: You may find it's your browser doing something strange because you are inserting table rows outside of a table...?

Comment: How can you use `<tr>` tag inside a `div` without `table` tag?

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid

Comment: @arulmr - You can't, the browser will just remove them as it thinks you are high and did something you should'nt have done.

Comment: @adeneo - That is what I'm also saying. In the question it is like that.

Comment: Why don't you just declare a javascript variable and have this tr in there?

Comment: @arulmr - That's actually my bad, was intended for the OP, just got the nicks wrong!

Comment: @HanletEscaño Becaus I don't want to have HTML all over the place...

Comment: Why these downvotes? Is my question not clear to you??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<tr>` and `<td>` is only valid inside `<table>` Being inside `div` it is simply ignored. You should put it inside a table:
http://jsfiddle.net/PQXxV/5/

And here is a code:

```
$('table').append($('.new').html());

alert($('.new tbody').html());
​
```

For a html like this:

```
<div class="new" style="display:none;">
    <table>
       <tr>
           <td><strong>New</strong></td>
           <td>Hi</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

your markup is invalid, just because you write your html text like that doesn´t mean the browser will parse it as you want it, it has rules and if you markup is invalid it will try to fix it for you.

if its a template you are after you could use the script tag:

```
<script type="x-template" class="new">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>New</strong></td>
        <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Old</strong></td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PQXxV/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="new">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>New</strong></td>
            <td>Hi</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Access it using `$(".new table").html()`, and then cut out the necessary values.

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome, if you inspect the div with class `new`, you will find that Chrome will strip out the `<tr>` and `<td>` to leave just this:

```
<div class="new" style="display:none;">    
        <strong>New</strong>
        Hi    
</div>
```

Which is what the alert returns. So, to answer your question, `.html()` returns the full html.

Answer (score 0):

Browser does not render html exactly we write, it ignores some tags and add some extra tags, that occurs with your example.
it ignores tr and td because of missing table element

[Here is JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/PQXxV/8/)

```
<div class="new" style="display:none;">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>New</strong></td>
        <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) documentation,

> This method uses the browser's **innerHTML property**. Some browsers may
>   not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original
>   document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the
>   quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric
>   characters.

Your html structure is invalid, as `tr` cannot be nested directly into `div`. You should change that to `table`, and everything will work.

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class="new" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>New</strong></td>
        <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>
</div>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Old</strong></td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Add a tbody tag and then use the below will get the result
$('table > tbody').append($('.new').html());
```